# Dapper factory object construction

Tags: c#, generics, dapper

I have something like the following query

```
_connection.Query<SomeType>(SELECT Id, Type, Time FROM table)
```

the thing is `SomeType` is a generic type

```
public class SomeType<T>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SomeTypeType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public T Object { get; set; }
}
```

right now I can define some sort of `SomeType<object>` or whatever, and in order to use the correct generic `SomeType<T>` I need to reconstruct the object.

what I want to be able to do is to have a line such as this that will actually work

```
var x =  _connection.Query<SomeType<object>>("...") as SomeType<OtherType>
```

(Obviously this is not a good example, but in my case it makes much more sense)

Any way, this obviously returns null, and just won't really work.

I thought maybe by defining some other way to construct the type, by maybe hooking to the way dapper initializes the type and defining a Factory or something.

Any suggestions to how I can actually do that?

Comment: so it's kind of nested object and you want to fill it through the query?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any configurable factories for the types used in Dapper.

I had a quick look at the code on github and there was nothing obvious, but I didn't do an exhaustive search.

There are [TypeHandlers](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.TypeHandler.cs), but they seem to be more for mapping value types, the properties on the model object, rather than modifying the modelobject itself.

So I think you'll have to handle this in a more manual way:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public SomeTypeType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public T Object { get; set; }
}

public class SomeType<T> : SomeType
{
    public T Object { get; set; }

    public SomeType() { }
    public SomeType(SomeType someType, T obj)
    {
        this.Id = someType.Id;
        ...
        this.Object = obj;
    }
}

var someType = _connection.Query<SomeType>("SELECT Id, Type, Time FROM table");
var obj = new Foo();
var specialisedSomeType = new SomeType<Foo>(someType, obj);
```

The manual mapping from 'SomeType' to 'SomeType' in the constructor can get tedious, so you could use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to handle that bit.